# Find in more than one collection MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I understand that MongoDB is a NoSQL database, and there are no joins, but is there a way to get data from two or more collections in just one request or one find.

I am asking this, because I don't want to do two or more calls or requests to find something, I want to improve the performance.

**For example**

I have:

```
var dogSchema = {
  dogName: String,
  owner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Owner'}
};

var catSchema = {
  catName: String,
  owner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Owner'}
};
```

And I wish to find the name of all the pets of a specific owner, in just one find()

Comment: Can you explain the use case properly? What are the two collections?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera please check the example added

Comment: There's no way you can do that as far as I know. You'll have to go for two `find` calls that too one inside the other.

Comment: If you really want to improve the performance, then you should change your schema. I don't really think there's a need for two different schemas. You can have just a single schema for Owner and embed the cats and dogs as embedded JSON objects in a `pets` array inside the Owner's Document

Comment: The reason MongoDB doesn't support JOINS is because MongoDB is designed for High performance and Scalability and JOINS aren't scalable.

Comment: well, it was just an example my schemas are much bigger than that, and they are not similar between them.

Comment: Okay. Still if you're really looking for performance, then I suggest that you go with embedding. And if embedding isn't an option for you, then you'll have to go with two `find` calls in your case.

Comment: @davidrl1000 Please do not ask artificial questions. They don't help you and spawn discussions eating up everybody's time.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can't do this. MongoDB's basic design is focused on queries always affecting only one collection.

There is one exception. The [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) operator can perform a limited left outer join with another collection. But this does not apply in the example from this question.

When you want to search documents together, put them into the same collection. MongoDB is a heterogeneous database which allows documents of different types in the same collection. So storing cats and dogs in the same collection `Pets` is technically possible and very likely also makes practical sense (depending on how similar they are in regards to your business logic, of course).

Comment: I got an approach very similar to the answer I was looking for, thank you. PD: This solution only works with mongodb 3.2 or higher